# Form in design mode missing close button and tab name

Tags: ms-access

How do I turn the option on to see the tab name of the form and the close button as viewed below.  In another database, a previous developer turned it off and when I edit that database, I don't see those controls (Form tab and close button)
[image: Form tab with close button]

This form appropriately has the tab name and a close button on the right.

[image]

****Please look at the image below. I am showing it in design mode to prove a point.  What I have outlined both in red and in green  - are missing. Yes, both in "Form view" and in "Design view" they are missing.  This makes it a struggle to develop in because I have to close Access in order to close the form. Right-clicking does not offer 'close' or design in the contextual menus.  How do I get them back?

[image]

Comment: On upper picture shown form designer window in tabs mode, on bottom picture shown tab control, not form designer tabs, they are different things. Please clarify what needed here or show bottom picture with entier Access window.

Comment: I have reposted a picture that shows an entire form and what is missing. It's just the top part that is missing.

Comment: Can you show actual picture, where controls you mention are missing?

Comment: And what is file type?Regular accde?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to File->Options->Current Database and check "Display Documents Tabs" checkbox. Also you can change designers presentation style to Overlapped Window", in some cases it may be more comfortable for design.

The designer window, including windows without tabs can be closed by pressing Ctrl-F4

Comment: Yes that's what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Ctrl+W also closes forms, it's a bit more convenient than Ctrl+F4.

Answer (score 0):

Go to :

- Form in design view
- Properties
- Format
- Min Max buttons  -> Set to : Both Enabled